# Где ошибки в орфографии?

Tags: орфография

Русский язык даёт колоссальные возможности для полёта мысли, считается одним из лучших в мире. Вот такая сложность языка, как правило, приводит к подсознательному страху излагать мысли, у его носителя, народа. Боятся превратиться в объект насмешек.

По нормам могу написать, как пожелаю:
Где Вы учились? Так неграмотно писать.
Так неграмотно писать. Где Вы учились? 
Так неграмотно писать, где Вы учились? 
Где Вы учились, так неграмотно писать?

Смысловая нагрузка ложится на вопрос «где Вы учились?»

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка у Вас не орфографическая, а пунктуационная: *Вот такая сложность языка, как правило, приводит к подсознательному страху излагать мысли(,) у его носителя, народа.*  Стиль книжный - публицистический или научный, значит, никаких авторских разговорных  "пояснений" допускать не следует. Запятой нет: к страху какому? -излагать мысли - несогласованное определение, не оборот, не обособляется.

Есть ещё один недочёт - нелогичность употребления неполного предложения "Боятся превратиться в объект насмешек". В предыдущем предложении не было названо сказуемое во множ. числе. Кто ОНИ, кто боится? Народ - ОН, а боятся люди, носителИ и т. д.

Когда Вы пытались трактовать нормы, допустили синтаксические ошибки - в построении предложений, на них Вам указала Ларf. Так что орфографических действительно нет, но корявость речи налицо, она - причина пунктуационной ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Орфографических ошибок нет. Про другое Вы и не спрашиваете...Что касается ваших примеров, то я бы все-таки последние два предложения разделила, убрала запятую и поставила знак конца предложения. То есть первые предложения оформлены правильней.

Просьба: формулируйте вопросы четче.

Comment: Ларf,   
Не кормите троллей.
http://mathhelpplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=26048

Comment: Что тролль видно из первой же фразы. так сказать, по ссылке не ходи.

Comment: А в чем смысл?

Comment: Ларf, по новым данным британских ученых тролль непостижим.
Он троллит потому, что он тролль.
Хотя в данном случае все довлоьно прозрачно. 
Он троллит одновременно несколько форумов, таская с одного на другой сомнительные тезисы и вопросы. И везде зарабатывает известность. Здесь он пока тих, но кончит плохо. Для нас всех - плохо.

Answer (score 1):

> Где Вы учились, так неграмотно писать?

Хотелось просто спросить: "Где Вы учились так неграмотно писать?"